# Integrate blog into own website

Tags: wordpress, blog-engine

There are already several questions with a similar title, but they received either no answers, or the answers were too specific.

I would like to integrate a blog into a website, so that content can be updated using a simple interface, e.g. from a wordpress/blogger/... account. I find the solutions with iframe cumbersome and unprofessional and I am not sure that modding a wordpress/blogger/... theme gives satisfactory results either, plus, I am not fond of running a whole wordpress engine on my website.

I build my light-weight websites from scratch (in gedit, Notepad for Linux), so I am not tied to any particular system or software and have full control over the layout.

Do you have any suggestions for achieving a satisfactory solution? Will I have to learn ASP.NET and IIS?

Many thanks.

Comment: *There seems to be no IIS alternative for Linux* [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) would like a word.

Comment: OK, apologies to Apache. I just looked at the requirements for the Subtext blog engine, which lists IIS. Does that mean that I can replace this requirement with Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is a good solution for your system. It's easy to install and use.

Requirements from [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress):

- WordPress server requirements for Version 3.2:

  o PHP version 5.2.4 or greater

  o MySQL version 5.0.15 or greater

  o (Optional)(Required for MultiSite) Apache mod_rewrite module (for clean URIs known as Permalinks)

It is also required that you install it on Apache. So, no need to learn ASP.NET and IIS.

If you want to have a blog, just pust the wordpress files in a folder called blog and install it there. You will then be able to access the website from `yourdomain.com/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I think integrating WP will be the best solution.. [Integrating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

And for the IIS alternative, ChiliASP can be an alternative for IIS on Linux, but costs $$$ and I heard it wasn't working well. Alternative to that, learn PHP/MySQL. You'll never regret learning it, and you'll never go back to IIS/ASP. Linux/GNU opens doors like you wont beleive.

Comment: Thanks, sounds better, since I've used MySQL before.

Comment: This can not be the answer. you are asking to learn PHP as a solution? There is always a work around for a problem.